# return non-persisting data as part of object

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

in Hibernate is there a way to return an object or list of objects that have derived data that isn't persisted in the table as part of an object?

for example if you had an object of tweets as follows:

```
long id;
String message;
long profile_id;

//non-persisted properties

long numLikes;
boolean isLiked;
```

then you had another object to keep track of who has liked the tweet such as

```
long id;
long liked_id;
long profile_id;
boolean liked;
```

how would I (can I) set up the tweet object so that I could see a count of likes inside the tweet object? the query would look something like

```
Select *, count(likes1.id) as numLikes, isNull(liked1.liked,0) as isLiked from tweets
left join (select id,liked_id from likes where liked_id = tweets.id) as likes1 on     tweets.id = likes1 .liked_id 
left join (select liked_id,liked from likes where profile_id = :authenticated_User) as     liked1 on tweets.id = liked1.liked_id
where.....
```

is there anyway I can stuff all of this in an object without using addScalar on every property in the tweets object? if not what is the proper way of doing this kind of set-up?

(assuming all properties are named correctly in sql query and data is returned as expected I know there are things in my example that will break.)

Comment: Use entities to map the columns of the corresponding table, and the associations with other tables. For the rest (aggregated values like count of retweets or likes), then use queries, and return DTOs containing the data returned by the query.

Comment: So your saying I would need to split the tweet object into two objects make a query to get the Tweet object then loop through the returned dataset and make another query for each tweet to return the aggregated values? that's the easy way but is there a way around it?

Comment: No, that's not what I meant. I meant that you should execute a query that would get the data you need from the database, all at once if possible, and use a DTO class to hold the data contained in each row returned by this query. Not everything must be an entity.

Comment: ok using spring and hibernate what is the syntax for that? can you write a quick example or send a link to somewhere that gives a good example of what your talking about?

Comment: Isn't it possible to use formula with join for that? Just interesting I need to replenish my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion doing it this way (use it only in case you do not use DTOs):

1) create class TweetRecordFilter to help filter TweetRecord

```
public class TweetRecordFilter(){

private long tweetId;
private long personId;
private long profileId;
private boolean liked;

//create setters and getters for all attributes mentioned above

}
```

2) create method for finding TweetRecords (you said they keep track of who like what)

```
public List<TweetRecord> findTweetRecordByFilter(TweetRecordFilter tweetrecordFilter){
     // return found records that have properties that were set to tweetRecordFilter
     // I suggest do a select using PreparedStatement 
     /* here write that code*/
}
```

3) create method for selecting Tweets

```
public Tweet findTweetById(int tweetId){
     // find tweet that has tweetId and say you have found one, let's call it "foundTweet"
     // I suggest do a select using PreparedStatement
     /* here write that code*/

     // find all tweetRecord that have specific profile_id
     TweetRecordFilter tweetRecordFilter = new TweetRecordFilter();
     tweetRecordFilter.setProfileId(foundTweet.getProfileId);
     tweetRecordFilter.setLiked(true);
     List<TweetRecord> tweetRecords = findTweetRecordByFilter(tweetRecordFilter);

     // set the number of likes for tweet
     if(tweetRecords != null){
         foundTweet.setLikesCount(tweetRecords.size());
     } 

     return foundTweet;
}
```

So all put together in a practical example:

```
int tweetId = 1;
Tweet tweet = findTweetById(1);
int numberOfLikes = tweet.getNumberOfLikes;
```

More on preparedStatement you can find [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html).